# Confusion regarding memory management in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I'm asking this question because I don't want to spend time writing some code that duplicates functionalities of the OpenGL drivers.

Can the OpenGL driver/server hold more data than the video card?  Say, I have enough video RAM to hold 10 textures.  Can I ask OpenGL to allocate 15 textures without getting an GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error?

If I can rely on the driver to cleverly send the textures/buffers/objects from the 'normal' RAM to the video RAM when needed then I don't really need to Gen/Delete these objects myself.  I become limited by the 'normal' RAM which is often plentiful when compared to the video RAM.

Comment: Because the memory management depends on the system (could differ from system to system) and multiple applications could use OpenGL at the same time you can't even be sure that you can use the all of the memory the graphic card has. So you would not get around to have an own _resource management_. This could be from interrest for you: [Determining Available Video Memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552372/determining-available-video-memory)

Comment: Yes the driver should do that. However it's likely to be very slow once it starts swapping textures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some additional information to my comment that did not fit in there.

There are different reasons why this is not part of OpenGL.

It isn't an easy task for the system/driver to guess which resources are and will be required. The driver for sure could create an internal heuristic  if resource will be required often or rarely (like CPU does for *if statements* and doing pre executing code certain code parts on that guess). But the GPU will not know (without knowing the application code) what resource will be required next. It even has no knowledge where the geometry is places in the scene (because you do this with you model and view martix you pass to your shader yourself)

If you e.g. have a game where you can walk through a scene, you normally won't render the parts that are out of the view. So the GPU could think that these resources are not required anymore, but if you turn around then all this textures and geometry is required again and needs to be moved from *system memory* to *gpu memory*, which could result in really bad performance. But the Game Engine itself has, because of the use of octrees (or similar techniques) and the possible paths that can be walked, an in deep knowledge about the scene and which resource could be removed from the GPU and which one could be move to the GPU while playing and where it would be necessary to display a loading screen.

If you look at the evolution of OpenGL and which features become deprecated you will see that they go to the direction to remove everything except the really required features that can be done best by the graphic card, driver and system. Everything else is up to the user to implement on it's own to get the best performance. (you e.g. create your projection matrix yourself to pass it to the shader, so OpenGl even does not know where the object is placed in the scene).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  I've never touched OpenGL before 3.3 so I don't know how bloated it used to be.  I'll create my own caching mechanism then, since I know what is needed when, and I'm happy that I don't really need to take into account what OpenGL does behind my back.

Comment: @Niriel Well it is a thin line, on the one hand it is useful to know what is done behind the scenes to understand what could lead to bottlenecks (e.g. if it is better to use texture lookups or attribute divisor if you draw multipel instance with one call or if a restructuring of the problem would enable more parallelisation on the gpu) on the other hand it may carry a risk to optimize for an system implementation or certain vendor gpu, instead of rethinking the problem.

Answer (score 7):

The approach "memory is abundant so I don't need to delete" is bad, and the approach "memory is abundant, so I'll never get out of memory errors" is flawed.

OpenGL memory management is obscure, both for technical reasons (see t.niese's comment above) and for ideological reasons ("you don't need to know, you don't want to know"). Though there exist vendor extensions (such as ATI_meminfo) that let you query some *non-authorative* numbers (non-authorative insofar as they could change the next millisecond, and they do not take effects like fragmentation into account).

Generally, for the most part, your assumption that you can use more memory than there is GPU memory is correct.

However, you are not usually not able to use all available memory. More likely, there is a limit well below "all available RAM" due to constraints on what memory regions (and how large regions) the driver can allocate, lock, and DMA to/from. And even though you can normally use more memory than will fit on the GPU (even if you used it exclusively), this does not mean careless allocations *can't and won't* eventually fail.

Usually, but not necessarily, you consume as much system memory as GPU memory, too (without knowing, the driver does that secretly). Since the driver swaps resources in and out as needed, it needs to maintain a copy. Sometimes, it is necessary to keep 2 or 3 copies (e.g. when streaming or for ARB_copy_buffer operations). Sometimes, mapping a buffer object is yet another copy in a specially allocated block, and sometimes you're allowed to write straight into the driver's memory.
On the other hand, PCIe 2.0 (and PCIe 3.0 even more so) is fast enough to stream vertices from main memory, so you do not even strictly need GPU memory (other than a small buffer). Some drivers will stream dynamic geometry right away from system memory.

Some GPUs do not even have separate system and GPU memory (Intel Sandy Bridge or AMD Fusion).

Also, you should note that deleting objects does not necessarily delete them (at least not immediately). Usually, with very few exceptions, deleting an OpenGL object is merely a tentative delete which prevents *you* from further referencing the object. The driver will keep the object valid for as long as it needs to.

On the other hand, you *really should* delete what you do not need any more, and you should delete early. For example, you should delete a shader immediately after attaching it to the program object. This ensures that you do not leak resources, and it is guaranteed to work. Deleting and re-specifying the in-use vertex or pixel buffer when streaming (by calling `glBufferData(... NULL);` is a well-known idiom. This only affects your view of the object, and it allows the driver to continue using the old object in parallel for as long as it needs to.

Comment: Thanks for the details, it make sense now.  My first idea was to use all the available memory and wait for out-of-memory errors to signal when I should delete/swap things (ask for forgiveness rather than permission).  But gl_out_of_memory isn't recoverable, so I am left with guessing/hoping I won't overfill it.  I guess profiling is the way to go here, I choose a memory budget and try to stay inside.

I haven't toyed with vertex animation yet, so I don't know much about streaming and don't understand glBufferData(..null..).  Would you mind explaining that?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my TL;DR answer, I recommend reading Daemon's and t.niese's answers as well:

> Can the OpenGL driver/server hold more data than the video card?

Yes

> Say, I have enough video RAM to hold 10 textures. Can I ask OpenGL to allocate 15 textures without getting an GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error?

Yes. Depending on the driver / GPU combination it might even be possible to allocate a single texture that exceeds the GPU's memory, and actually use it for rendering. At my current occupation I exploit that fact to extract slices of arbitrary orientation and geometry from large volumetric datasets, using shaders to apply filters on the voxel data in situ. Works well, but doesn't work for interactive frame rates.