# Determine size of compiled shader in memory

Tags: opengl, memory, graphics, directx, shader

Once you have compiled say a vertex shader at runtime in OpenGL or DirectX is it possible to determine its footprint in GPU memory?

Comment: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552372/determining-available-video-memory) thread useful.

Comment: Indeed.  I was aware it is fairly useless information. While I can quickly estimate the size of my textures I cannot shaders.  I have a reason to load several thousand or more.  I am more curious what my upper limit might be.  This is not for optimization.  I am guessing though the only way to do this is to query available mem, load a shader, query available memory and subtract.  So in that sense, the thread solves it.

Comment: The shader is likely to be compiled in an intermediary language. The final binaries size could change when the driver or the hardware change

Comment: Nine years later you probably don't care, but this is a top search engine hit for the question. For all the people saying you can't, or you shouldn't, here is an entire [section](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Binary_upload) direct from Khronos about retrieving the actual compiled binary (which is not portable, of course).

Answer (score 4):

In OpenGL you can use `glGetProgramiv` with `GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_LENGTH` (docs [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glGetProgram.xml)). This is the length of the program as returned by `glGetProgramBinary` - it may not reflect the actual footprint in GPU memory.

Comment: GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_LENGTH is undefined. Link is broken. Sorry,GuyRT, have to find another solution...

Comment: @DmitryBabich it's a docs bug ([issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Refpages/issues/85)), the answer is technically correct, although Ivan's is more detailed.

Answer (score 4):

While I'm still curious why would you need this, I think, that only driver knows how exactly shader binary uploaded to device (which parts? when? is it uploaded at all? all of shaders at once or one-by-one?). There is no way to estimate device memory footprint of shader from high-level APIs such as OpenGL and DirectX. You even don't know at which point of time it gets to device memory. And if it gets it at all.

Still you can get size of binary on CPU side, to have an idea of what numbers we are talking about.

- In DirectX you can query size of binary from [`ID3DBlob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that was returned by [`D3DCompile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, by invoking its [`ID3DBlob::GetBufferSize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. Example (error checking omitted for clarity):

  ```
  ID3DBlob* pBinary = 0;
  D3DCompile(..., &pBinary, &pErrorMsgs);
  size_t binarySize = pBinary->GetBufferSize();
  ```
- In OpenGL you can use [`glGetProgramiv()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glGetProgram.xml) function with `GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_LENGTH`, as already stated in GuyRT's answer. Example (error checking omitted for clarity):

  ```
  GLint binarySize = 0;
  glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_LENGTH, &binarySize);
  ```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Apparently for some drivers you also have to add this _before_ the link step, otherwise the returned size is always zero: `glProgramParameteri(program, PROGRAM_BINARY_RETRIEVABLE_HINT, GL_TRUE)`