How do you query an Intel GPU for total memory?
I'm currently getting a GPU's total memory from GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info or GL_ATI_meminfo. However, testing this code with an Intel Arc card neither extension is supported (makes sense). However, looking at the extensions that are supported by the card nothing seems to cover this. Even looking at intel extensions none seem relevant. Is there really no way to get this info via OpenGL Querying the card?

What extensions does it expose?

There's 245 supported extensions, I can add them to the question. But to my understanding, the NV and ATI extensions are typically the gotos for card memory information. Is there another extension that would provide it?

This technique should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553146/4641116
